# Omit the newline character in reading file with c++

Tags: c++, string, newline, getline

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream path("test");
    std::string separator(" ");
    std::string line;
    while (getline(path, line, *separator.c_str())) {
        if (!line.empty() && *line.c_str() != '\n') {
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }

        line.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The file "test" is populated with numbers, separated by various number of spaces. I need to read only the numbers, one by one and omit spaces and newlines. This code omits the blank spaces but not the newline character.

These are few lines from the input file "test":

```
     3        19        68        29        29        54        83        53
    14        53       134       124        66        61       133        49
    96       188       243       133        46       -81      -156       -85
```

I think the problem is that this `*line.c_str() != '\n'` is not the proper way to determine if the string `line` hit newline character and the program keeps printing the newlines!

This one works great:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream path("test");
    std::string separator(" ");
    std::string line;
    while (getline(path, line, *separator.c_str())) {
        std::string number;
        path >> number;
        std::cout << number << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `*line.c_str() != '\n'` you should probably check that the line doesn't contain only whitespaces. Hard to say without seeing an example of the input (please make it so we can see where the `'\n'` characters are).

Comment: You're only checking if the first character is newline. If a number is at the end of the line, the newline will be the last character of `line`, not the first character.

Comment: Why don't you use `path >> number;`, which will skip over any whitespace and read a single number.

Comment: Wouldn't just `path >> number;` read a number and skip all the whitespace?

Comment: What's the point of `path.seekg(currentPosition)`? You're already at that position, you don't need to seek to it. Similarly, `path.seekg(0, std::ios::beg)` is unnecessary immediately after opening the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the stream operator `>>` to read integers:

```
std::ifstream path("test");
int number;
while(path >> number)
    std::cout << number << ", ";
std::cout << "END\n";
return 0;
```

This will list all the integers in your file, assuming they are separated with space.

The correct usage for `getline` is `getline(path, line)` or `getline(path, line, ' ')` where the last argument can be any character.

`*separator.c_str()` in this case converts to `' '`. This usage is not recommended.

Likewise `*line.c_str()` points to the first character in `line`. To find the last character use

```
if (line.size())
    cout << line[size()-1] << "\n";
```

When using `getline(path, line)`, `line` will not including the last `\n` character.

Here is another example with `getline`. We read the file line by line, then convert each line to `stringstream`, and then read the integers from each line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream path("test");
    std::string line;
    while(getline(path, line))
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        int number;
        while(ss >> number)
            std::cout << number << ", ";
        std::cout << "End of line\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) function built into C++.

Comment: Will this function take into account the sign?

Comment: no, but you could always make a test for it, isdigit only filters out non digit numbers.